# Resolve Unconverted Data Remains: Error without replace other file contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, datetime, strptime

I am currently writing a script which sorts dates. I have a input file which is called `sample.txt` and an output file called `sample2.txt`. At the end the contents of the input file should be sorted and written to the output file. But when running my script I am running into the following error: `Unconverted Data Remains: Dentist`. It is caused because `strptime` cannot convert `Dentist`. So my question is: How I can fix this error without deleting the word Dentist or other none date contents?

This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 156, in <module>
    main_user_input.user_input()
  File "test3.py", line 144, in user_input
    list_next_appointments.list_next_appointments_main()
  File "test3.py", line 96, in list_next_appointments_main
    bands = sorted(bands, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
  File "test3.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    bands = sorted(bands, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
  File "/home/supre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/home/supre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  Dentist
```

This is the content of my input file:

```
23.08.2021 Dentist 
13.08.2031 Surgery 
13.01.2022 Family
```

This is my code:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file1, open('sample2.txt','w+') as file2:
    bands = (line.strip() for line in file1)
    bands = sorted(bands, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
    file2.write(' \n'.join(bands))
```

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file is always going to be formatted the way you showed it, that is in 2 columns, the easiest way to avoid the error would be to use `.strptime` to only convert the date column. In other words, split the line into the date text and rest:

```py
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file1, open('sample2.txt','w+') as file2:
    bands = (line.strip() for line in file1)
    bands = sorted(bands, key=lambda line: datetime.strptime(line.split()[0], "%d.%m.%Y"))
    file2.write(' \n'.join(bands))
```

Comment: thank you very very much for your fast response and help:) This fixed it for me:)